# web api 2 controller multiple post methods

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-post

I have a controller with the default post method. I want to add one more with a different name and action. The problem is when I make the request POST (http://localhost:57926/api/Users/Login) it doesn't execute Login method, it executes the default PostUser method.

How can I fix this?

```
 // POST: api/Users
    [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostUser(User user){
         //Some code
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Login")]
    public IHttpActionResult Login(JObject form)
    {
       //some code
    }
```

Comment: How are you registering "PostUser" method's route?

Comment: Make sure you have added `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in WebApiConfig